# Problems with AnimationListener

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to write a nice animation, but there were difficulties.

In the code below, it works but not as much as I need. The first button shows the animation, but the second and third show no animation. what am I doing wrong?

animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >
    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" >
    </alpha>
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

my code:

```
public class PurchaseMenu extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private int mAnimationsFinished = 0;
    private Button kitchenBtn;
    private Button hotelBtn;
    private Button engenerBtn;
    private Animation fallingAnimation;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.purchase_menu, null);
        fallingAnimation  = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.falling);
        kitchenBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonKitchen);
        hotelBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonHotel);
        engenerBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonEngener);
        fallingAnimation .setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                Log.d("mylognah", "start" + " " + mAnimationsFinished);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                if (mAnimationsFinished == 0) { //kitchenBtn animation ended
                    hotelBtn.setAnimation(fallingAnimation);
                } else if (mAnimationsFinished == 1) { //hotelBtn animation ended
                    engenerBtn.setAnimation(fallingAnimation);
                }
                mAnimationsFinished++; //This would be a member variable
                Log.d("mylognah", "finish" + " " + mAnimationsFinished);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
        kitchenBtn.setAnimation(fallingAnimation);
        kitchenBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        hotelBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        engenerBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change these lines:

```
if (mAnimationsFinished == 0) { //kitchenBtn animation ended
                    hotelBtn.setAnimation(fallingAnimation);
                } else if (mAnimationsFinished == 1) { //hotelBtn animation ended
                    engenerBtn.setAnimation(fallingAnimation);
                }
```

to this:

```
if (mAnimationsFinished == 0) { //kitchenBtn animation ended
                    hotelBtn.startAnimation(fallingAnimation);
                } else if (mAnimationsFinished == 1) { //hotelBtn animation ended
                    engenerBtn.startAnimation(fallingAnimation);
                }
```

Comment: Now the behavior is: called animation on the first button. where it ends is called animation again but all three buttons.

Comment: after complete the animation then remove the animation listener. like this:  fallingAnimation.setAnimationListener(null);

Comment: in onAnimationEnd()  method.

Answer (score 1):

Try startAnimation instead of setAnimation:

```
 @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                if (mAnimationsFinished == 0) { //kitchenBtn animation ended
                  kitchenBtn.clearAnimation();  
                  hotelBtn.startAnimation(fallingAnimation);
                } else if (mAnimationsFinished == 1) { //hotelBtn animation ended
                  hotelBtn.clearAnimation();   
                  engenerBtn.startAnimation(fallingAnimation);
                }
                mAnimationsFinished++; //This would be a member variable
                Log.d("mylognah", "finish" + " " + mAnimationsFinished);
            }
```

**setAnimation**

Sets the next animation to play for this view.But view animation does not start yet.

**startAnimation**

If you want the animation to play immediately, use startAnimation. This method provides allows fine-grained control over the start time and invalidation, but you must make sure that

1) the animation has a start time set,

2) the view will be invalidated when the animation is supposed to start.

Comment: Now the behavior is: called animation on the first button. where it ends is called animation again but all three buttons.

Comment: Then, you can try clearing animation on the views you don't want to animate. For instance, right before start hotelBtn animation, call clearAnimation() on kitchenBtn

Comment: Thanks your advice was more complete!

Comment: just one more small problem. The third button on the animation still is not called (

Comment: See my edited answer. You should call clearAnimation each time. I try this and it works for me